# How to count number of arguments of a function, in javascript, INCLUDING optional arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, if I have the following function in javascript:

```
var f1 = function(a, b, c) {}
console.log(f1.length); // 3
```

But with this function, the output is different:

```
var f2 = function(a, b, c = 6) {}
console.log(f2.length); // 2
```

How do I count number of arguments of `f2` INCLUDING optional arguments?

Comment: It's actually a very interesting question

Comment: What is the larger problem that you're trying to solve? What would you be able to do if you got a good answer, in other words?

Comment: @Pointy that is what I'm trying to determine as well. Maybe its a test question? If he's building this in an actual web app I would just reconsider what he is doing.

Comment: @Gianni in my experience the not-so-misguided motivations for questions like this have to do with building automated tests

Comment: @Pointy I want to force that user pass a callback with exactly 2 arguments, even one of them is defined as optional. So, I need to know how to count the number of arguments (INCLUDING optional arguments) of a function in Javascript. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: With the answer, I can throw a error in my JS library if user not pass a callback with exactly the numbers of arguments, independently if user define one of the arguments as optional. By this way, the using of the library will be consistent and without bad use (and possibly potential strange behavior) from the user.

Comment: That's not at all an idiomatic JavaScript architecture.

Comment: To put it another way, experienced JavaScript programmers would think that that is a bizarre and irritating feature of your API, since additional parameters absolutely don't hurt anything.

Comment: @PedroFurtado What if someone passes a bound function? There's no way to derive the number of parameters for them.

Comment: @PedroFurtado Make it a warning, not an error. And add a way to suppress/disable the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's a bit of a mess but I believe this should cover most edge cases.

It works by converting the function to a string and counting the commas, but ignoring commas that are in strings, in function calls, or in objects/arrays. I can't think of any scenarios where this won't return the proper amount, but I'm sure there is one, so this is in no way foolproof, but should work in most cases.

```
function getNumArgs(func) {
  var funcStr = func.toString();
  var commaCount = 0;
  var bracketCount = 0;
  var lastParen = 0;
  var inStrSingle = false;
  var inStrDouble = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < funcStr.length; i++) {
    if (['(', '[', '{'].includes(funcStr[i]) && !inStrSingle && !inStrDouble) {
      bracketCount++;
      lastParen = i;
    } else if ([')', ']', '}'].includes(funcStr[i]) && !inStrSingle && !inStrDouble) {
      bracketCount--;
      if (bracketCount < 1) {
        break;
      }
    } else if (funcStr[i] === "'" && !inStrDouble && funcStr[i - 1] !== '\\') {
      inStrSingle = !inStrSingle;
    } else if (funcStr[i] === '"' && !inStrSingle && funcStr[i - 1] !== '\\') {
      inStrDouble = !inStrDouble;
    } else if (funcStr[i] === ',' && bracketCount === 1 && !inStrSingle && !inStrDouble) {
      commaCount++;
    }
  }

  // Handle no arguments (last opening parenthesis to the last closing one is empty)
  if (commaCount === 0 && funcStr.substring(lastParen + 1, i).trim().length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  return commaCount + 1;
}
```

Here are a few tests I tried it on: https://jsfiddle.net/ekzuvL0c/

Comment: Doesn't work for `getNumArgs(a => {})` or `getNumArgs(function(a){}.bind(null))` but is otherwise very thorough!

Comment: Thanks for this parser. [Fiddled around](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ku05m6r/) with it, now works for `a => {}`

Answer (score 0):

A bit workaround but you can do like this.

```
function sum(x,y,z){
    return {
        result:x+y,
        length:arguments.length
    }
}

var x = sum(1,2);
document.body.innerText = x.result + " | " + x.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm Coming from Mozilla Web Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length

It looks like because the variable is actually passed into the function and not defined as optional argument, the length method works. But since you have optional argument the length method does not pick up the optional argument.

A workaround could be checking if the argument passed within the argument so console.log each argument then see what they output. remember that  you could also pass in a function so instead of c=6, this could be converted to another external function where basically you return c which = 6 within that other function then it gets put into the new function as (a,b,c)

Edit: Yea I just checked and it looks like your optional argument is not even in the function. also you don't describe how the function is being called. f2(1,1,c=6) You are not calling the function properly. f2(1,1,c=6); will give you the entire result. not having 2 established arguments and then trying to define the third parameter within the function

Answer (score 0):

It gets even better. Try moving the default param for instance…

```
var f3 = function(a, b = 6, c) {}
console.log(f3.length); // => 1
```

Or giving it a rest/spread…

```
var f4 = function(...args) {}
console.log(f4.length); // => 0
```

But that's cool because someone left us `Function.toString` you can use to print out the string representation of the entire function and then write some regex against to reliably get the length for at least the next year.

Comment: You cannot write a regex to reliably get the length.

Comment: Sure you can. And it would be a fool's errand.

Comment: Yeah, js is not a regular language :-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the best way but what about

```
f2.toString().split(',').length
```

Edit: Well if there's commas INSIDE the function this wouldn't work, may need to regexp it a bit more.

How about:

```
f2.toString().match(/^function\s*\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(',').length
```

Answer (score -1):

Outside the function, I think the only way now is to parse the definition, something like this works:

```js
var f1 = function(a, b, c = 6) {console.log(",,,,,,")}

console.log(f1.toString().split("{")[0].match(/,/g).length+1)
```

Comment: See my answer, I think this won't work if there are any commas _inside_ the function itself, since `toString` prints out the function's contents as well.

Comment: I don't think there really *is* a good way though, right? It seems to be a problem that has no elegant solution afaik.

Comment: @RoseRobertson :) I just see your answer with the same approach, and yes, I think there is no elegant solution.